# How can I merge two data frames with different length and with two conditions in R?

Tags: r, merge

I want to merge two data frames with different lengths and two condtions. In particular, I want to add the score from df1 to df2 depending on the year and the Country (From). The logic is similar to the function VLOOKUP in Excel with two conditions. How can I achieve this with minimal code?

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
                  Year Country   Score  
                  1    NE         0.8     
                  1    UK         0.9     
                  2    NE         0.7     
                  2    UK         1     
                  ",header = T)

df2 <- read.table(text = "
                  Year From     Vote   To 
                  1    NE         1    Ger 
                  1    NE         2    I
                  1    UK         2    Ger
                  1    UK         3    I  
                  2    NE         2    Ger  
                  2    NE         2    I  
                  2    UK         4    Ger  
                  2    UK         2    I  
                  ",header = T)
```

Comment: ```library(dplyr); df2 %>% right_join(., df1, by = c("Year" = "Year", "From" = "Country"))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `left_join` with `by` to join by multiple columns. You can use the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
df3 <- left_join(df2, df1, by = c("From" = "Country", "Year" = "Year"))
```

Output:

```
  Year From Vote  To Score
1    1   NE    1 Ger   0.8
2    1   NE    2   I   0.8
3    1   UK    2 Ger   0.9
4    1   UK    3   I   0.9
5    2   NE    2 Ger   0.7
6    2   NE    2   I   0.7
7    2   UK    4 Ger   1.0
8    2   UK    2   I   1.0
```

Comment: Thank you, perfect answer. I should have thought of left_join but I was stuck in my thoughts.